# Pass parameter to form action in HTML

Tags: php, html

I am trying to implement a simple file upload using the files here :

```
http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/05/ajax-image-upload-and-resize-with-jquery-and-php
```

I have it working and managed to change the styles etc via CSS and change the filenames etc etc.

I now need to use this in an iframe and pass a variable for the filename.

In my app I can use either localstorage,setItem('clientID',10) or add a parameter to the iframe url. www.xxx.com/uploads?clientID= 10.

The plugin has an html file that then calls the php file with :

```
<form action="processupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="MyUploadForm">
```

So what is the 'correct' method to get my clientID variable to the final.php file.

Can I use javascript in the HTML file and pass the variable to the form action ie:

```
<form action="processupload.php?"+clientID method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="MyUploadForm">
```

Or can I grab the url parameter in the html file and add to the form action.

I tried this after the body tag:

```
<?php
$clientID='100';
?>
```

Then changed the form action to :

```
<form action="processupload.php?clientID=" <?php echo $clientID ?> method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="MyUploadForm">
```

Then in the PHP file I added:

```
$clientID = $_GET["clientID"];
```

and changed the filename details to:

```
$NewFileName        = $clientID.$File_Ext; //new file name
```

The process works as I get the file uploaded but the clientID is blank. eg the file is name '.png' instead of '100.png'

MrWarby

Comment: Why not just set it in a session and accews that session in the upload processing script?

Comment: you store the value in session $_session['clientID']=100;

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to do it through HTML....

Instead of

```
<form action="processupload.php?clientID=" <?php echo $clientID ?> method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="MyUploadForm">
```

Try this:

```
<form action="processupload.php?clientID=<?php echo $clientID ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="MyUploadForm">
```

If that still doesn't work (some servers don't like mixing POST and GET), then try swapping for this:

```
<form action="processupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="MyUploadForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="clientID" value="<?=$clientID;?>" />
    <!-- the rest of your form -->
</form>
```

And then in your PHP file, swap the `$_GET` for `$_POST`.

Comment: Cheers @Mark Ormesher. That worked. Is there any form of syntax checker for HTML it seems a nightmare to work with......

Comment: @user3193843 IDEs like Adobe Dreamweaver (if you can call it an IDE!) will highlight syntax errors as you work. I think even more basic software like Programmer's Notepad has some form of error detection, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form method="post" action="shopping_cart.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $product["id"];?>">
```

C:\xampp\htdocs\project\cat1.php on line 30
">

getting this error while passing values

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35083663)