# How to pass a hidden parameter back to the form action

Tags: php, html, forms

I am working on a restaurant search and review project. I have a search page that will show restaurant names and provides a link for the user to add a review for each restaurant result by using the hidden input `rid`.

In my review.php, I am using the value sent in for the hidden input `rid` to run another simple query and then display the name of the restaurant. Then I have several inputs so the user can input their name, their rating of the restaurant, and finally a comment.

```
<form action="comment.php" method="GET">
  <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="rid" VALUE="">
  <?php
        $db=mysqli_connect(//parameters);

        $restaurant_id= $_GET['rid'];

        if (!empty($_GET)){
            $result = $db->query(//query);

            $row = $restaurant_result->fetch_assoc() 
            echo $row["name"];
        }
  ?>


  <INPUT //other inputs for the user>

</form>
```

My problem is that when the user hits a `submit` button at the bottom, the page will refresh with the url `www..../review.php?rid=` meaning that the name of the restaurant can't be displayed since no restaurant id parameter is being resent in the form. How can I send the restaurant id back to the page again once it is done?

I tried the top answer in this thread but I get the same url problem: [Pass parameter to form action in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453038/pass-parameter-to-form-action-in-html/24453212)

Comment: What are those ```<ul>``` elements doing there?

Comment: sorry should've removed those for clarity, they are just to produce a list for formatting purposes in html. Doesn't do anything to the workings of the code itself.

Comment: I would replace those with ```<div>``` with a proper class for formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="rid" VALUE="<?php if(isset($_GET['rid'])){echo $_GET['rid'];} ?>">
```

Comment: Thank you! Just a small clarification for anybody that might need this in the future, it should be ```<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="rid" VALUE="<?php if(isset($_GET['rid'])){echo $_GET['rid'];} ?>">```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to XSS...[escape your HTML output.](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/06/preventing-xss-vulnerabilities-in-php-everything-you-need-know)